# Trying to have multiple source files linked with one header in C

Tags: c, linker, declaration

I am developing a program in C and I need to have one .h file and two .c files that share the same name on the methods but have different implementations. So basically what I am trying to do is:

header.h --->

```
void f();
void d();
```

source1.c --->

```
#include "header.h" 

void f(){
   print("Hello");
}

void f(){
   print("World");
}
```

source2.c --->

```
#include "header.h" 

void f(){
   print("My name");
}

void f(){
   print("is Danni");
}
```

but I have an error of multiple declarations :(

So I was wondering if there is any kind of trick about how to do this, maybe using macros or somenthing like that.

Thanks...

Comment: That error would be because that is *exactly* what you have. Four, in fact, of the same function, `f()`. Pick a different name for each? I *think* the problem you're supposed to be solving is *implement* `f()` and `d()` in source1.c, then *use* them in `main()` in source2.c, which includes `"header.h"` and your program is linked with object code from each compiled .c file. At least thats my guess.

Comment: So we're in some other file and we call `f()`. __What happens?__ Which of these 4 functions gets called? What is supposed to happen when we call `f()` from within a function in `source1.c`?

Comment: That did not work for me, since the whole point of what I am trying to do is handle always the same names...

Comment: introduce why you need this. this is weird. lots of cross platform libraries do that, but they never try to link two functions share the same name.

Comment: ok so what i really wanted to do from the begining is to have source1.c and source2.c and their respectives headers individually and call one or the other according to a parameter in the main(), and for my facility use the same names in all the methods, but that also gave me the same problem...

Comment: I wonder if what you really want to do is to create an object-oriented program with two different _classes_, each of which has an `f()` function and a `d()` function. Then your `main()` function can easily choose which class is used. That is easily done in C++. You can write object-oriented code in C if you work really hard at it and tolerate a lot of ugly syntax, but if you have a C compiler you very probably have a C++ compiler too, so unless you are in a particularly restricted environment (no C++) I don't see the point in doing such a thing in C.

Comment: ok so i am forced to use a bunch of ifs and that's exactly what i was trying to avoid... :(

Comment: If these files had not caused a linker error, what would your `main()` function have been? Maybe seeing that code will give us an idea what you wanted these functions for, and why.

Comment: Perhaps you want to learn about function pointers.

Comment: Rename your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two solutions ..

#### The first solution (not recommended)

It is based entirely on the compilation process. You simply compile the source.c file with the main function with the source you want to use. This should work without errors simply because the compiler is not aware of the other file. This is not recommended because it provides the same functionality (at some extent), use the same header file but are **seperated source files**. You might risk losing one of them. Also, you have to be aware of that whenever you're compiling a program that uses that header.

#### The second solution (recommended)

It is based on the preprocessing step, which is much more safer than the compilation command because it works the same with any compiler options or commands.

You have to use *Macro Conditionals* because they're processed before compilation. The behaviour of macro conditionals is almost entirely based on variable existence or comparison.

You can use something like that:

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H
#define _HEADER_H

void f();
void d();

#ifndef _HEADER_H_2 /* Where this is the default behavior if nothing the macro wasn't defined */
# include "source1.c"
#else
# include "source2.c"
#endif

#endif /* _HEADER_H */
```